# what does the "text+=" part of this code do?

Tags: javascript

I want to understand how this forloop works in Javascript. The part that confuses me the most is the "text+=" part.

I commented next to all the lines that I think I understand. Any clear explanation of the whole code will be much appreciated.

I have played around with the code via w3schools website - where I came across it.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits, text;
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

text = "<ul>"; //start of list

fruits.forEach(myFunction); //for each fruit add 

text += "</ul>"; // end of list
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text; // add to html

function myFunction(x) {  // function with one parameter to parse
  text += "<li>" + x + "</li>";
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x+=y` is a syntactic sugar for `x=x+y`, which means that these two are same.

So, in your case:

- `text += "</ul>";` would just append `</ul>` closing tag to the `text` variable;

  and
- `text += "<li>" + x + "</li>";` would be equivalent of `text = text + "<li>" + x + "</li>"`.

Comment: @bipll in terms of atomicity?

Comment: Not in this particular case, of course, but in generic case LHS would be evaluated only once.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you mean. Can you briefly elaborate on that?

Comment: `the_longest_evluation() = the_longest_evaluation() + 42;`

Comment: I understand the x=x+y part. so text = text + x. but I don't get the function part. "text = text + "<li>" + x + "</li>". how does it know not to keep including the ul tag every time is goes through the loop?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri How does it know not to keep including the first ul tag every time is goes through the loop? thanks

Comment: You first asked about `x+=` only. I have now edited my answer and see if it is better for you.